# Regular measure on Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to do the following problem:

Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on the Borel sets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\mu$ takes finite values on the compact sets. Let $\mathcal H$ be the class of Borel sets such $E$  with $$(i) \space \mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(G), E \subset G, G \space \text{open}\},$$$$(ii) \space \mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K), K \subset E, K \space \text{compact}\}$$

Prove that the open and compact sets are in $\mathcal H$. If $\mu$ is finite, then $\mathcal H$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

It is clear that if $O$ is open then $O$ satisfies $(i)$, analogously, if $K$ is compact then $K$ satisfies (ii). Now, I have no idea how to show that $O$ and $K$ satisfy (ii) and (i) respectively.

As for the second part, I am pretty lost as well. I am trying to prove that if $A \in \mathcal H$, then $A^c \in \mathcal H$, and that if $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathcal H$, then so is its union.

I can write $\mu(A^c)=\mu(X \setminus A)=\mu(X)-\mu(A)$ (here I use $\mu(X)<\infty$), but I don't know how to use the fact that $X,A \in \mathcal H$.

Any suggestions to do this exercise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is an "official" source? Epimorphic's answer seems perfectly fine, and it does provide suggestions just as you ask. You don't need any source to do the exercise, just the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- To show that compact sets satisfy (i), use the metric on $\mathbb R^n$ to construct a decreasing sequence $\{G_n\}$ of open sets whose intersection is the compact set. What can you say about the measures of the $G_n$ and their relation to that of the compact set?
- To show that open sets satisfy (ii), build your approximations using dyadic $n$-cubes $\prod_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{m_i}{2^k}, \frac{m_i + 1}{2^k} \right]$ where $m_i \in \mathbb Z$ and $k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$.
- When $\mu$ is finite, the following equivalent definition of $\mathcal H$ may be more useful:

  > $E \in \mathcal H$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open $G$ and a compact $K$ such that $K \subset E \subset G$ and $\mu(G \setminus K) < \epsilon$.

  Closure of $\mathcal H$ under complementation should be essentially straightforward now.

  For closure under countable unions, choose for each $E_n$ sufficiently tight $G_n$ and $K_n$, and use them to construct $G$ and $K$ that are of the required tightness around $\bigcup E_n$.

Be careful that in several places, the most "natural" approximations from the inside might not necessarily be closed and/or bounded, hence not compact. A major part of this exercise is finding workarounds for this issue.